# PHP trader_macd() sending always false

Tags: php

I try to use the `trader_macd()` function in PHP. But it always returns `bool(false)`. I tried different parameters, values for the array but i always get the same. PECL is enabled and the function answers but i never get a good calculation.

Anyone knows if this is an issue of the trader.so extension or from my code?

```
$values = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27);   
$macd = trader_macd($values, 12, 26, 9);

var_dump($macd);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's your result and what's your expected result?

Comment: formatted code as code instead of blockquote

Comment: thanks for the formatting.

I get bool(false), and i would like to get an array with 3 computed average value.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. Apache was sending an error message

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/trader.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/trader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory i$ 
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/trader.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/trader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory i$
```

There were two modules installed at the same time. On in 20131226 and one in 20121212. So i removed the oldest and it works like a charm!